# How to make AJAX wȯrk on PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and currently trying to get a simple PHP-AJAX to show the server time after I click the 'show server time' button. But it doesn't show the time after I click it. Can anyone help me? Here's the show_server_time.php code:

```
<?php include('header.html'); ?><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Ajax Server Time
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="get_server_time()">
        Show Server Time
      </button>
      <br><br>
      <div id='showtime'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
```

The ajax.js:

```
function getXMLHTTPRequest(){
  if(window.XMLHTTPRequest){
    //for modern browsers
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    //for old IE browsers
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
}

function get_server_time(){
  var xmlhttp = getXMLHTTPRequest();
  var page = 'get_server_time.php';
  xmlhttp.open("GET",page,true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = '<img src = ajax_loader.png>';
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

And this is the get_server_time.php:

```
<?php
echo date('H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Use the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check the console window for any errors.

Comment: it said 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined', and when i deleted the activexobject, it said 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')'. what should i do? :( thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Ajax Server Time
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="get_server_time()">
        Show Server Time
      </button>
      <br><br>
      <div id='showtime'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<script>
function get_server_time(){
  var xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
  var page = 'get_server_time.php';
  xmlhttp.open("GET",page,true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = '<img src = ajax_loader.png>';
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

It works as above.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: thank you, it worked! but may i know why i can't use the <script src=ajax.js></script> instead of writing the function in my show_server_time.php?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you use <script src="ajax.js"></script> format, you may not be able to see the changes you have made to the js file, you need to clear your browser history.

Comment: i see. thank you!:D